# How to cleanly establish and destroy half-open TCP connections in c#

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, network-programming, discovery

Assuming I'm running on Windows Server 2008 R2, which as per MSDN doesn't have the restrictions documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548(v=vs.85).aspx), how would I go about establishing a half-open TCP connection and C# and subsequently closing it. I want to do this as cleanly as possible. Of course half-open connections are probably not very clean to begin but non the less.

I believe i need to use a raw socket but other than that, I'm not sure. Do i use a protocol type of TCP or of IP and then build the TCP Syn packet myself?

Comment: Maybe open the socket in a child AppDomain then unload the AppDomain whilst the socket is connected?